# How do I generate random numbers with a mean in C++?

Tags: c++, c++11, random

How do I generate 100 random numbers in between 1,000 and 20,000, with a total mean of 9,000 in C++? I am looking into the C++ 11 Libraries but am not finding a method that allows me to include a mean AND a range.

Comment: What distribution do you want?

Comment: Any distribution is fine. What would be the best in this scenario?

Comment: If you don't know what you want, you almost certainly want a "normal distribution", also know as a "gaussian distrubition".

Comment: A normal distribution would give you a mean of 10500 ((20000-1000)/2 + 1000).  The curve would be slightly biased get a mean of 9000.

Comment: There's hardly a use case where a specific mean could matter while the distribution is irrelevant. You should try describing your actual problem so we can give a useful answer. What you are saying is equivalent to "I want to generate a number with a '1' in it, but I don't care what base the number is written on."

Comment: `pow((double)rand() / RAND_MAX, (1.0 - mean) / mean) * (maximum - minimum) + minimum`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since you are flexible on distribution, an easy solution that still gives reasonable results, without having to do rejection logic, is a [triangular distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_distribution).  I.e. you set the lower end of the triangle at 1,000, the upper end of the triangle at 20,000, and the tip of the triangle such that you get your desired mean of 9,000.

The wikipedia link above indicates that the mean of a triangular distribution is:

```
(a + b + c) / 3
```

where `a` and `b` are your lower and upper limits respectively, and `c` is the tip of your triangle.  For your inputs, simple algebra indicates that `c = 6,000` will give your desired mean of 9,000.

There is a distribution in C++'s `<random>` header called `std::piecewise_linear_distribution` that is ideal for setting up a triangular distribution.  This needs only two straight lines.  One easy way to construct such a triangular distribution is:

```
std::piecewise_linear_distribution<> dist({1000., 6000., 20000.},
                                          [](double x)
                                          {
                                              return x == 6000 ? 1. : 0.;
                                          });
```

Now you simply have to plug a URNG into this distribution and crank out the results. For sanity's sake it is also helpful to collect some statistics that are important according to your problem statement, such as minimum, maximum, and mean.

Here is a complete program that does this:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <numeric>
#include <random>
#include <vector>

int
main()
{
    std::mt19937_64 eng;
    std::piecewise_linear_distribution<> dist({1000., 6000., 20000.},
                                              [](double x)
                                              {
                                                  return x == 6000 ? 1. : 0.;
                                              });
    std::vector<double> results;
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
        results.push_back(dist(eng));
    auto avg = std::accumulate(results.begin(), results.end(), 0.) / results.size();
    auto minmax = std::minmax_element(results.begin(), results.end());
    std::cout << "size = " << results.size() << '\n';
    std::cout << "min = " << *minmax.first << '\n';
    std::cout << "avg = " << avg << '\n';
    std::cout << "max = " << *minmax.second << '\n';
}
```

This *should* portably output:

```
size = 100
min = 2353.05
avg = 8972.1
max = 18162.5
```

If you crank up the number of sampled values high enough, you will see convergence on your parameters:

```
size = 10000000
min = 1003.08
avg = 8998.91
max = 19995.5
```

Seed as desired.

Answer (score 6):

Since you don't care about the distribution as long as it satisfies your constraints, by far the easiest thing to do is to simply produce `9000` all the time. And the simplest distributions that are not that are things like producing `1000` with probability `p` and `20000` with probability `1-p`, where you've solved for the value of `p` that gives the correct mean.

I strongly suspect you should figure out the math/statistics of what you're trying to do before you start thinking about programming anything.

Comment: If I do use normal distribution, I would have to provide a standard deviation, which would bring the average down, correct?

Comment: how do i choose a standard deviation that allows the generator to potentially pick every number in the range, but keep the mean at 9,000?

Comment: @user3647894 Short answer: you cannot. You have to "chop" the tail of the Gaussian, hence you won't have a Gaussian anymore. Otherwise any value in a Gaussian distribution has a non-zero probability of occurrence.

Answer (score 2):

Here is how to do this with a normal distribution, using a sample-discard technique to keep values within bounds. This of course skews the distribution so it is no longer normal. How big of a deal this effect depends on your original choice for the standard deviation. How much this matters to you depends on your application.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>

double get_random_number_with_minimum_mean_and_maximum(
    double minimum,
    double mean,
    double maximum
) {

    // Any uniform random generator of your choice could be used here.
    // Obviously making this static is not rentrant or thread-safe.
    static std::mt19937 generator;

    // We'll start with a normal distribution with a standard deviation set
    // such that ~99.7% of the time we'll get a number within the average width
    // of your upper and lower bounds.
    //
    // Why ~99.7% and not some other number? Because that corresponds to three
    // standard deviations, and you didn't specify any requirements, so I'm
    // just making assumptions on your behalf.
    double const average_bound_width = ((mean-minimum) + (maximum-mean)) / 2;
    double const standard_deviation  = average_bound_width / 3;
    std::normal_distribution<double> distribution(mean, standard_deviation);

    // Now, keep fetching numbers until we find one that is within our desired
    // bounds. Throwing numbers away randomly from a normal distribution does
    // not affect the mean, but since our bounds are going to be skewed, our
    // mean will probably get skewed slightly, but this will likely not be
    // very noticable.
    double value;
    do {
        value = distribution(generator);
    } while (value < minimum || maximum < value);

    return value;
}

int main() {
    for (int i=0; i<100; ++i) {
        std::cout << get_random_number_with_minimum_mean_and_maximum(
            1000,
            9000,
            20000
        ) << '\n';
    }
}
```

When I run this, I get this output:

```
9426.01
10458.7
9518.42
9945.55
9032.35
7268.34
11092.2
13705.6
6374.58
7290.7
7008.3
10075.4
15678
8089.93
5645.39
13607.6
11930.2
13799.4
12194.7
10390
8594.2
14625.4
10487.9
11116.9
9473.06
13868
12414.5
12711.2
9431.92
3570.35
3490.47
3974.69
6695.1
8642.8
10034.3
8757.84
10232.6
10441.1
18234.9
9862.67
2365.8
9982.83
10282
13492.3
11932.6
9399.23
7196.37
11793.8
9646.56
1232.16
7796.91
13297.7
13191.4
8340.9
9891.94
7998.53
8139.9
8813.12
8829.3
9408.99
7771.22
6957.75
6149.01
7139.31
1482.41
5893.11
12720.9
6009.68
12360.5
5557.36
3080.25
8922.16
7636.47
12109.1
11153.5
5434.98
8874.9
8599.4
7833.87
8525.87
7630.14
8595.15
9786.19
12644.8
6310.17
12696.1
8717.86
7199.22
7404.67
7410.03
6041.42
7930.46
6505.42
7772.88
4929.65
4686.06
7743.93
5211.43
12023.2
10380.5
```

The mean is ~8980, which is pretty close to 9000 for only 100 samples.

If I run this with 1 million samples, the mean is ~9049.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a ["power-shifted" distribution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28599247/194586) that is continuous, can return any value in the range, and executes in one go. The mean is as desired, but the mode will usually be at either end closest to the mean.

```
double shiftable_distribution(double minimum, double mean, double maximum)
{
    double range = maximum - minimum;
    double scaledmean = (mean - minimum) / range;
    return pow((double)rand() / RAND_MAX, 
               (1.0 - scaledmean) / scaledmean) 
                * range + minimum;
}
```

What the distribution actually looks like (for 1000, 9000, 20000)

[image]