# spyder plotting with dots for a pdf

Tags: python, function, matplotlib, plot, spyder

I am trying to plot with dots hoping in the end i can get a probability density function simulation. My code is:

```
import random
import math
from numpy import *
from matplotlib.pyplot import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as pl


clock_offset=3000

y=0

p=0.50

for i in range (40):

    x = random.random()
    if x < p:
         clock_offset+=1

         for 'bo' in (clock_offset,y):
             y+=1
         pl.plot(clock_offset,y,'bo')
         pl.axis([2980, 3040, 0, 40])
         y=0
    else:
       clock_offset-=1

       for 'bo' in (clock_offset,y):
           y+=1
       pl.plot(clock_offset,y,'bo')
       pl.axis([2980, 3040, 0, 40])
       y=0
```

The problem is i can't write a for loop that makes y+=1, when that place (clock_offset,y) has already been occupied with a dot. Any solutions?

Comment: What did you intend to do actually? That `for 'bo' in (clock_offset,y): y+=1` makes no sense. What's the string `'bo'` got to do with it?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what this code of yours is supposed to do. But take a look at [this answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28598001/c-generate-random-numbers-within-an-interval-with-respect-to-a-mean/28598074#28598074) that explains how to get a random number on a distribution. Bellow I gave you a rewrite of that C++ code into python.

```
import random
import math
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def GausPDF(x, a=1., b=2., c=3.):
    return a*math.exp(  -((x-b)*(x-b)/(2*c*c)   ))

def random_on_PDF(PDF, top, bottom, maxPDF):
    x = (top-bottom)*np.random.random()+bottom
    y = maxPDF*random.random()

    while(y>PDF(x)):
        x = (top-bottom)*np.random.random()+bottom
        y = maxPDF*random.random()

    return x,y


x, y, = list(), list()
for i in range(0, 1000):
    a,b = random_on_PDF(GausPDF, 10., -5., 1.)
    x.append(a)
    y.append(b)

plt.scatter(x,y)
plt.show()
```

Using this code and [THIS](http://matplotlib.org/1.4.1/examples/animation/histogram.html) matplotlib example directly, you can simulate how random voting affects/builds a PDF.

Is that what you're after?